# mysql 8 - rds - 1022 Can't write; duplicate key in table

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

Documenting this error and solution here in case it could help anyone.
We have a MYSQL 8 database on Amazon RDS.
The below group by used to work just fine on Mysql 5.7 but it started giving
 `1022 Can't write; duplicate key in table  '/rdsdbdata/tmp/#sqlf80_1656bc_0'`
 error once we upgraded to Mysql 8.

```
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(CONCAT(YEAR(performance_stats_date),'-',  
MONTH(performance_stats_date),'-',DAY(performance_stats_date)),
 '%Y-%m-%d')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two solutions we found:
1. Either **reduce the number of columns** in the query (in our case we have about 800 columns in this particular query, reducing it to less than about 100 solved the problem)
2. or **simplify the group by statement** to something like `GROUP BY performance_stats_date`

Answer (score 1):

That's the wrong way to use `DATE_FORMAT`.  It is given a `DATE` or `DATETIME` and a string providing the 'formatting'.  Example:

```
mysql> SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), "%Y-%m-%d"), DATE(NOW());
+--------------------------------+-------------+
| DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), "%Y-%m-%d") | DATE(NOW()) |
+--------------------------------+-------------+
| 2019-01-30                     | 2019-01-30  |
+--------------------------------+-------------+
```

In your case, it would be something like

```
  GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(performance_stats_date, "%Y-%m-%d")
```

But this is even simpler:

```
  GROUP BY DATE(performance_stats_date)
```

For further discussion, please provide

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'char%'
SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table.
the entire query
```

Answer (score 1):

Error caused when query creates an internal temporary table while executing a query and internal_tmp_mem_storage_engine=TempTable (default) setting.

most likely you will see this error for queries with the group by clause and when tables use by query has a large number of columns.

This is a bug in MySQL-8 and the following is a workaround for now.

**Workaround:**

```
SET session internal_tmp_mem_storage_engine=MEMORY;
```

Run Query.

Comment: How does this solve the asker's problem? Just looking at it it seems very unlikely that this would help at all, so an explanation would be very helpful here.

Comment: @Colin'tHart updated

Comment: I'm having this on `8.0.23`. Removing `with rollup` in group by clause removed the error message

Comment: Still have the problem on `8.0.25`. `SET session internal_tmp_mem_storage_engine=MEMORY;` didn't help.

Comment: This worked for me on 8.0.23 (AWS Aurora)

Answer (score 0):

The most likely you already have a constraint with the name "x" (the one you are trying to create).

Constraints must be unique for the entire database, not just for the specific table you are creating/altering.

To find out where the constraints are currently in use you can use the following query:

```
SELECT `TABLE_SCHEMA`, `TABLE_NAME`
FROM `information_schema`.`KEY_COLUMN_USAGE`
WHERE `CONSTRAINT_NAME` = 'x';
```

as a solution you can try to use another name for this constraint.

Comment: In our case that was not the problem. I've documented our particular case in the answer above in case anyone else has the same problem.